# ColdFusion cfhttp strips out newline character from parameter

Tags: coldfusion

Before calling the function below, the `text1` value was encoded ie:

> ```
> http://example/exampleProxy.cfc?returnFormat=plain&method=update&id=443&blah=something&text1=bob+bob2%0Abob
> ```

But the request that is sent has stripped out the newline character ie

```
http://example/test/id=443&blah=something&text1=bob+bob2bob
```

**Function:**

```
<cffunction name="update" access="remote" output="yes" returntype="string">
        <cfargument name="id" required="yes" type="string" />
        <cfargument name="blah" required="yes" type="string" />
        <cfargument name="text1" required="yes" type="string" />   

        <cfhttp url="#variables.cString#" method="PUT"      timeout="#variables.HTTP_TIMEOUT#">
            <cfhttpparam name="id" type="url" value="#arguments.id#">
            <cfhttpparam name="blah" type="url" value="#arguments.blah#">
            <cfhttpparam name="text1" type="url" value="#arguments.text1#">
        </cfhttp>
        ...
```

Comment: workaround: encode "%0A" to "\n", is that ok?

Comment: Silly question, but are you sure it is removed? What test are you using to verify the url? If you are viewing it in HTML be sure to use `<pre>`/`htmleditFormat()` so you can view white space characters. I ran a quick test on the same CF9 server and new lines were not removed.

Comment: Which version of CF are you using?

Comment: I am using CF9.  I noticed that it is removed before I get to the cfhttp function as well.  I did a dump and it was removed.

Answer (score 2):

From what you have described, I suspect the new line character is there. But you would not be able to see it with a simple `<cfdump var="...">` because it displays the results html. So any new line characters will just appear as a single space:

```
TEXT1: bob bob2 bob
```

You either need to use `format="text"` or `<pre>` tags. Then you should see the new line character in the value:

**Code:**

```
<cfdump var="#arguments#" format="text">
<pre>TEXT1: #arguments.text1#</pre>
```

**Results:**

```
BLAH: something
ID: 443
TEXT1: bob bob2   <--- new line
bob


TEXT1: bob bob2  <--- new line
bob
```

I tested your code with CF9, and the new line was present inside the function and on the receiving page. ie `CGI.QUERY_STRING`

```
  id=443&blah=something&text1=bob%20bob2%0Abob
```

Comment: Thanks I think you are correct.  But it still seems that cfhttp strips out the newline.

Comment: What test are you using to verify this? If this receiving page is a non-CF server, you try barnyr's suggestion of using something like Fiddler to inspect what is being sent.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to confirm whether anything is being stripped is to run [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and add proxyserver="localhost" proxyport="8888" to your  call. the call will be routed through fiddler and you can inspect all the parameters from there